javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used
I have the following Spring Boot Service used to encrypt and decrypt Strings:
@Service
public class EncryptionServiceImpl implements EncryptionService {
    // Strong AES key (256-bit)
    private static final String AES_CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private static final int AES_KEY_SIZE = 256;

    // Generate a strong secret key for AES encryption
    private SecretKey secretKey;
    private SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();

    private DataKeysRepository dataKeysRepository;

    @Autowired
    public EncryptionServiceImpl(DataKeysRepository dataKeysRepository) throws Exception {
        // Generate or load your AES SecretKey securely
        this.secretKey = generateSecretKey();
        if (this.secretKey == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("SecretKey generation failed!");
        }
        this.dataKeysRepository = dataKeysRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a strong AES SecretKey.
     * @return SecretKey
     * @throws Exception If key generation fails.
     */
    private SecretKey generateSecretKey() throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGenerator.init(AES_KEY_SIZE, secureRandom); // 256-bit AES key
        return keyGenerator.generateKey();
    }

    @Override
    public String encrypt(String plainText)
    {
        try {
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

            // Initialize cipher for encryption
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);

            // Encrypt the plain text
            byte[] encryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            // Combine IV and encrypted text for storage/transmission
            byte[] ivAndEncryptedText = new byte[iv.length + encryptedTextBytes.length];
            System.arraycopy(iv, 0, ivAndEncryptedText, 0, iv.length);
            System.arraycopy(encryptedTextBytes, 0, ivAndEncryptedText, iv.length, encryptedTextBytes.length);

            DataKeys data = new DataKeys();
            data.setText(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ivAndEncryptedText));
            data.setCreatedAt(OffsetDateTime.now());
            DataKeys key = dataKeysRepository.save(data);

            // Return UUID of the encrypted text
            return key.getId().toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String decrypt(String key)
    {
        Optional<DataKeys> byId = dataKeysRepository.findById(UUID.fromString(key));
        if (byId.isPresent()) {
            DataKeys dataKeys = byId.get();

            try {
                byte[] ivAndEncryptedText = Base64.getDecoder().decode(dataKeys.getText());

                // Extract the IV
                byte[] iv = new byte[16];
                System.arraycopy(ivAndEncryptedText, 0, iv, 0, iv.length);
                IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

                // Extract encrypted text
                byte[] encryptedTextBytes = new byte[ivAndEncryptedText.length - iv.length];
                System.arraycopy(ivAndEncryptedText, iv.length, encryptedTextBytes, 0, encryptedTextBytes.length);

                // Initialize cipher for decryption
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);

                // Decrypt and return as plain text
                byte[] decryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);
                return new String(decryptedTextBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

When I send a request to encrypt and decrypt the text it's working fine.
But when I restart the microservice and then I try to decrypt a String I get error:
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:861)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:941)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:734)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2244)

at this Java method: doFinal(...)
Do you know what is causing this issue?

In the code, it looks like you are using doFinal to encrypt ... not decrypt as you stated.  Is this the correct code or is your description wrong?

Either way, the problem is (it appears) that you are attempting to encrypt a byte array - plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) - that is not a multiple of AES block size - 128 bits == 16 bytes.  The data must be padded so that it is some multiple of 16 bytes long.

When you restart the service, EncryptionServiceImpl is (presumably) executed again. This will generate a new AES key, i.e. not matching the passed DataKeysRepository of the previous execution, causing (almost) all decryptions to fail with a BadPaddingException. So you need to add a mechanism that stores the AES key belonging to a DataKeysRepository somewhere.

@StephenC+ it's not a blocksize issue; PKCS5Padding allows the data to be any length, and even if you changed to NoPadding so the blocksize constraint does apply then wrong-size data would give a different exception not BadPadding.


But when I restart the microservice and then I try to decrypt a String I get error

keyGenerator.init(AES_KEY_SIZE, secureRandom); // 256-bit AES key

You generate a new key after each initialisation. To decrypt a cyphertext you need THE SAME key to encrypt and decrypt, so you need to preserve the key somewhere

Given final block not properly padded

Padding are extra bytes at the end of the ciphertext to fill the cypher block-size (256 bit in your case), but it must have a specific format. If a key changes, decrypting with a different key results in an invalid padding block

For encryption/decryption to work (return the data), you must store the key somewhere, which is in scope of SO. For encryption/decryption to have any benefit or purpose, you must store the key somewhere securely, which is trickier and in scope of security.SX.
